# Oldest publication of the lower bound on comparison sort

Tags: history

We all know that the worst case complexity for comparison sort is in $\Omega(n\log(n))$, but who was the first to publish this?

Everywhere I look, people have their own proofs but no reference to the original. A lot of them talk about Shannon Entropy which was published in 1948.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this paper: [A Tournament Problem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2308750) published in 1959. The authors show $\Omega(n \log n)$ lower bound for ranking of objects by means of pairwise comparisons.

[CLRS](https://edutechlearners.com/download/Introduction_to_algorithms-3rd%20Edition.pdf) cites this in Chapter Notes of Chapter 8.

Comment: This may not be the earliest, but I doubt I will find anything earlier.

Comment: @thedudehimself  paper is from 1959. It should be the earliest; otherwise, they would have cited the previously known result (if any).

Comment: The thing is that I suspect 'Goldstine, Herman H. and von Neumann, John. Planning and Coding of Problems for an Electronic Computing Instrument, 1947 April.' may have it, but I cannot find the text of that paper.

Comment: @InuyashaYagami it's perfectly possible that authors sometimes miss relevant references.